# how to send json header in websocket tornado python?

Tags: python-2.7, websocket, tornado

```
 def on_message(self, message):

     for client in ChatWebSocket.clients:
         print(client)
         t=json.loads(message)
         client.write_message(json.dumps('Content-type:application/json\n')) 
         client.write_message(json.dumps({'a':t['b']}))
         print(t['b'])
```

the problem  is  client is accepting  it  like a  normal  string  and  not a  header
please help

Answer (score 4):

From [Tornado's documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.write_message):

> `WebSocketHandler.write_message(message, binary=False)`
>
> Sends the given message to the client of this Web Socket.
>
> The message may be **either** a string **or a dict (which will be encoded as json)**. If the binary argument is false, the message will be sent as utf8; in binary mode any byte string is allowed.

So you don't need to dump anything. Just send the dict as is and Tornado will encode it as JSON anyways:
false, the message will be sent as utf8; in binary mode any byte string is allowed.

So you don't need to dump anything. Just send the dict as is and Tornado will

```
def on_message(self, message):
  for client in ChatWebSocket.clients:
    print(client)
    t = json.loads(message)
    client.write_message({'a': t['b']})
    print(t['b'])
```